# Android Studio - Long delay when selecting image through gallery

Tags: android, android-studio

New to Android Studio, just wondering if anyone can help on this delay when I send an image that is taken from the gallery. Once image is selected there is a long delay until it is actually sent, and for a moment the screen goes black as well.

Here is the code - thanks

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.launch_voip_call) {
        Utils.startCall(this, contact);
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.launch_camera) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Pick Image from")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //camera intent
                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(ConversationActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
                        cameraIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_CONTACT_JID", contact.getJid());
                        startActivity(cameraIntent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        // Show only images, no videos or anything else
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();


    }
    return false;
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 5, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent.SendMessage(contact.getJid(), byteArray, ""));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@OnTextChanged(R.id.compose)
public void onMessageChanged(CharSequence s) {
    sendButton.setVisibility(s.length() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
}

@OnClick(R.id.send)
public void onSend(final View view) {
    String message = composeText.getText().toString().trim();
    if (!message.isEmpty()) {
        if (!amIOffline()) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent.SendMessage(contact.getJid(), message));
            composeText.setText("");
        } else {
            SimpleSnackbar.offlineGroupChat(view).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Activity result is on Main Thread.. Compressing Image can take time.. Try to use AsyncTask to achieve compression in background and then send image in background as well.. Dont perform Compression on MainThread thats why you are getting long delay..

Let me know if you need code??

```
 public class ImageSendingAsync extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 5, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent.SendMessage(contact.getJid(), byteArray, ""));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}


//This will go in Activity Result
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();
               Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
         new ImageSendingAsync().execute(bitmap);
        }
```

Comment: Yes please if you can show me the code, as i am very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the compress takes a while and thats why ur MainThread are not able to draw the Layout -> Black Screen.

maybe test the time it take to compress the pic.

if the time is to long, use ASyncTask.

```
[...]
long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 5, stream);
long timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
Log.e("resizePicture Timer", "resize took " + (timeEnd - timeStart) + "ms");
[...]
```